# Attempting to process the first API call from Client

Tags: php

Let say client side making the first call the my API . How I process the first API call?
How should I  intercept the  http://www.mycom.com/api/GET?name=simple call inside api.php?

client.php

```
    <?php 
$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'http://www.mycom.com/api/GET?name=simple';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_GET, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$json = curl_exec($ch);
echo "\n".$json."\n";

 ?>
```

api.php  what's inside?

```
<?php

?>
```

Comment: I think if I want the api.php to intercept all api request from client, I have to modify on the .htacess file but I am not sure exactly what fields I need to add or change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding the following to your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^api/([a-zA-Z]+) api.php?mode=$1 [QSA]
```

when a client calls "api/GET?name=simple" this would be the same as "api.php?mode=GET&name=simple".

Comment: what about able to differentitae different folders? If api.php inside folder A.  And there also folder B, C,D inside htdocs.

Comment: So is that mean I need to specify the folder on the APi call?  like http://ww w.mycom.com/folderA/api/GET?name=simple?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you mean the client deal with:
http://www.mycom.com/api.php?name=simple

then, the standard way is to make deal with the client, like to tell hem that the first api call must say that it is the first:
http://www.mycom.com/api.php?name=simple&first

then you can know the first call in api.php

```
if (isset($_GET['first'])){
    // first call
} else {
    // not first call
}
```

otherwise, if you don't trust user (client), and think that he may do some bad things, you can know that it was the first api call by his IP.